# Iterative depth-first traversal with remembering value's paths

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I need help with specific implementation of iterative depth first traversal algorithm.
I have an object like this (it's just an example, object might have more properties and be deeper nested):

```
const root = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: {
      d: {
        e: 2,
        f: 3,
      }
    },
    g: [
      {
        h: 4,
        i: 5,
      },
      {
        j: 6,
        k: 7,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I need is a function that would traverse the whole object and return an array like this:

```
[
  {"a": 1},
  {"b.c.d.e": 2},
  {"b.c.d.f": 3},
  {"b.g.0.h": 4},
  {"b.g.0.i": 5},
  {"b.g.1.j": 6},
  {"b.g.1.k": 7},
]
```

I managed to create an algorithm that sort of solves my problem, but needs one additional step in the end. Result of the algorithm is an array of strings like that:

```
[
  'a^1',
  'b.c.d.e^2',
  'b.c.d.f^3',
  'b.g.0.h^4',
  'b.g.0.i^5',
  'b.g.1.j^6',
  'b.g.1.k^7'
]
```

so in order to achieve what I want I have to do one full iteration over the result of my algorithm, split strings by `^` symbol and then create objects based on that.

This is the part that I need help with - how can I improve/change my solution so I don't need to do that last step?

```
function dft(root) {
  let stack = [];
  let result = [];
  const isObject = value => typeof value === "object";
  stack.push(root);
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    let node = stack.pop();
    if (isObject(node)) {
      Object.entries(node).forEach(([childNodeKey, childNodeValue]) => {
        if (isObject(childNodeValue)) {
          const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(childNodeValue).map(([cnk, cnv]) => {
              return [`${childNodeKey}.${cnk}`, cnv];
            })
          );
          stack.push(newObject);
        } else {
          stack.push(`${childNodeKey}^${childNodeValue}`);
        }
      })
    } else {
      result.push(node);
    }
  }
  return result.reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd keep pairs `<keys,value>` in the stack and only create a string key when storing a newly created object:

```js
function dft(obj) {
    let stack = []
    let res = []

    stack.push([[], obj])

    while (stack.length) {
        let [keys, val] = stack.pop()

        if (!val || typeof val !== 'object') {
            res.push({
                [keys.join('.')]: val
            })
        } else {
            Object.entries(val).forEach(p => stack.push([
                keys.concat(p[0]),
                p[1],
            ]))
        }
    }

    return res.reverse()
}

//

const root = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: {
      d: {
        e: 2,
        f: 3,
      }
    },
    g: [
      {
        h: 4,
        i: 5,
      },
      {
        j: 6,
        k: 7,
      }
    ]
  }
}

console.log(dft(root))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push the `childNodeKey` `childNodeValue` pair directly as an object to your `result` array.

Change

```
stack.push(`${childNodeKey}^${childNodeValue}`);
```

to

```
const newEntry = {}
newEntry[childNodeKey] = childNodeValue
result.push(newEntry);
```

or with ES2015 syntax (you would need a transpiler for [browser compatibility](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/))

```
result.push({[childNodeKey]: childNodeValue});
```

Complete function:

```js
const root = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: {
      d: {
        e: 2,
        f: 3,
      }
    },
    g: [
      {
        h: 4,
        i: 5,
      },
      {
        j: 6,
        k: 7,
      }
    ]
  }
}

function dft(root) {
  let stack = [];
  let result = [];
  const isObject = value => typeof value === "object";
  stack.push(root);
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    let node = stack.pop();
    if (isObject(node)) {
      Object.entries(node).forEach(([childNodeKey, childNodeValue]) => {
        if (isObject(childNodeValue)) {
          const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(childNodeValue).map(([cnk, cnv]) => {
              return [`${childNodeKey}.${cnk}`, cnv];
            })
          );
          stack.unshift(newObject);
        } else {
          const newEntry = {}
          newEntry[childNodeKey] = childNodeValue
          result.push({[childNodeKey]: childNodeValue});
        }
      })
    } else {
      result.push(node);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(dft(root))
```

Comment: Yup, I thought about that but unfortunately, this way the order of objects gets messed up

Comment: To keep the order you can change `stack.push(newObject)` to `stack.unshift(newObject)`

Comment: nope, it doesn't even change the output

Comment: I have added the complete code snippet in my original answer. Isn't the output what you wanted?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I didn't follow your suggestions correctly. Yes, your code snippet returns correct output, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you almost got it complete. Just make the array entry an object just before pushing it into `result`. By splitting `Array.prototype.split('^')` you can get `'b.g.0.h^4'` >>> `['b.g.0.h', '4']`. So, rest is a cake:

```
if (isObject(node)) {
 ...
} else {
  const keyAndValue = node.split('^')
  // approach 1)
  // const key = keyAndValue[0]
  // const value = keyAndValue[1]
  // dynamic key setting
  // result.push({[key]: value});

  // approach 2)
  // or in short,
  // dynamic key setting
  result.push({[keyAndValue[0]]: keyAndValue[1]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stack where each item has an iterator over the children, and the path up to that point:

```js
function collect(root) {
    const Node = (root, path) => 
        ({ iter: Object.entries(root)[Symbol.iterator](), path });
    const result = [];
    const stack = [Node(root, "")];
    while (stack.length) {
        const node = stack.pop();
        const {value} = node.iter.next();
        if (!value) continue;
        stack.push(node);
        const [key, child] = value;
        const path = node.path ? node.path + "." + key : key;
        if (Object(child) !== child) result.push({ [path]: child });
        else stack.push(Node(child, path));
    }
    return result;
}

const root = {a:1,b:{c:{d:{e:2,f:3}},g:[{h:4,i:5},{j:6,k:7}]}};
console.log(collect(root));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the quickest fix to your code is simply to replace

```js
  return result.reverse();
```

with

```js
  return result.reverse()
    .map ((s, _, __, [k, v] = s .split ('^')) => ({[k]: v}));
```

But I also think that we can write code to do this more simply.  A function [I use often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20pathEntries) will convert your input into something like this:

```js
[
  [["a"], 1],
  [["b", "c", "d", "e"], 2],
  [["b", "c", "d", "f"], 3],
  [["b", "g", 0, "h"], 4],
  [["b", "g", 0, "i"], 5],
  [["b", "g", 1, "j"], 6],
  [["b", "g", 1, "k"], 7]
]
```

and a fairly trivial wrapper can then convert this to your output.  It could look like this:

```js
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [[Array.isArray(obj) ? Number(k) : k, ... p], v])
      ) 
    : [[[], obj]]

const transform = (o) => 
  pathEntries (o) 
    .map (([k, v]) => ({[k .join ('.')] : v}))

const root = {a: 1, b: {c: {d: {e: 2, f: 3, }}, g: [{h: 4, i: 5, }, {j: 6, k: 7}]}}

console .log (transform (root))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

---

I don't know your usecase, but I would find this output generally more helpful:

```js
{
  "a": 1, 
  "b.c.d.e": 2, 
  "b.c.d.f": 3, 
  "b.g.0.h": 4, 
  "b.g.0.i": 5, 
  "b.g.1.j": 6, 
  "b.g.1.k": 7
}
```

(that is, one object with a number of properties, rather than an array of single-property objects.)

And we could do this nearly as easily, with a small change to `transform`:

```js
const transform = (o) =>
  pathEntries (o) 
    .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => ((a[k .join ('.')] = v), a), {})
```